# SQL Server CASE Statement in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, case

Hi I am working on  query that involves having to use CASE. I keep getting an error and cannot figure out why. Below is what I have tried.

```
SELECT 

   CASE 

     when LineItem like '%Apple%' THEN ProductType = 'Apple'
     when LineItem like '%Orange' THEN ProductType = 'Orange'
     when LineItem like '%Strawberry' THEN ProductType = 'Red'
     when ProductType like 'Yellow' THEN ProductType
     else ProductType = 'White'

   end as ProductType

FROM Fruits
```

The error I get is on the "=" symbols. 
Is it not possible to have two different columns after the WHEN keyword in T-SQL?

Comment: Get rid of `ProductType =`. Just use `ELSE 'White'`

Comment: Remember that `ProductType like 'Yellow'` acts as `=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this...

```
SELECT 
    ProductType = CASE 
                        WHEN f.LineItem like '%Apple%' THEN 'Apple'
                        WHEN f.LineItem like '%Orange' THEN 'Orange'
                        WHEN f.LineItem like '%Strawberry' THEN 'Red'
                        WHEN f.ProductType like 'Yellow' THEN f.ProductType
                        ELSE 'White'
                    END
FROM 
    dbo.Fruits f;
```

Answer (score 3):

Just a syntax error.  No need for `Then ProductType = '...'`

```
SELECT 
   CASE 
     when LineItem like '%Apple%' THEN 'Apple'
     when LineItem like '%Orange' THEN 'Orange'
     when LineItem like '%Strawberry' THEN 'Red'
     when ProductType like 'Yellow' THEN ProductType
     else 'White'
   end as ProductType
FROM Fruits
```